# How to get row index of listview from custom list adapter?

Tags: android

I have two layouts

1. `main.xml`  -----   With a single ListView (say listview_01).
2. `row.xml` ----- With an ImageView(say imageView_01) & a TextView(say textView_01)

I am filling my `listview_01` with `row.xml` as row using array data i have.
I wanted to perform an operation on `onclick()` event of `imageView_01`, its working.
i have added `onClick()` on `imageView_01` in `getView()` in my `CustomlistAdapter`.

But can anyone tell me how to get row index in onClick() event of listview_01 of a row image, in a CustomListAdapter?

**Here is My CODE**

Apologize but i cant upload my whole activity & adapter code

**SOME ACTIVITY CODE**

```
listView_episodesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mQuickAction.show(arg1);

    }
});
```

**SOME Adapter Code**

```
ImageView imageView_EpisodePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_episode_pic);
drawableManager.fetchDrawableOnThread(episodeTemp.episodeImage, imageView_EpisodePic);

imageView_EpisodePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "Click on image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

From my activity i can access the listView row index i clicked. But from adapter i can't.
I Just want to get **row index** in `ListView(main.xml)` on click on `ImageView (row.xml)`

Comment: paste your adapter and activity code

Comment: Waqas, please refer my code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `mListView.getPositionForView(v);` in the `onClick(View v)` which will return the index of the listview item. (Note that: I don't know the adapter, I'm just guessing you can use it)

Answer (score 0):

Your `onItemSelectedListeneter()` will have adapter view and position and also id.. in which position is what you need (`arg1`)

Comment: sandy, OnItemSelectedListener() is for ListView onClick(). i want to attach onclick() event on imageView in a row & in onClick of imageView i wants to fetch row index.. i think that is possible only from custom cursor that i have made to fill my listview

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and was surprised that I couldn't find a better way to do this from within the custom adapter class. Nikola's solution would work from within the Activity or Fragment class, but not in the custom adapter as far as I can tell.

I had a problem setting the tag on the ImageView attribute of my object where the first index [0] would not return properly, but setting the tag of the 'name' attribute of my object worked flawlessly. I'm going to continue to look for a better way to do this, but for now this seems to work ok.

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_project, null);

            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textProjectName);
            viewHolder.desc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textProjDesc);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgProj);           
            viewHolder.name.setTag(position);

            Log.d(TAG, "Position: " + position);


            viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Image Selected at Index: " + viewHolder.name.getTag());
                }

            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).name.setTag(list.get(position));
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.desc.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The row id of an item in the list is being set as the id of the "convertView".

> convertView.setId(position)

When an item is pressed/selected, the row id of that item is fetched inside the OnClickListener.

> ```
>       convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 // item position is fetched here. this is exactly the same position of the selected item in your list
>                 int selectedPosition = v.getId();
>             }
>         });
> ```

You may set the id for any child of the convertView. For example,

> convertView.imageView.setId(position);

Then fetch the id as following,

> ```
>     imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             int selectedPosition = v.getId();
>         }
>     });
> ```

Full function

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup vg) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_book_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        // ...

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (listItems.size() > 0) {
        // item position is set here. this is exactly the same position of your item in the list
        convertView.setId(position);
        convertView.imageView.setId(position);

        // ...

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // item position is fetched here. this is exactly the same position of the selected item in your list
                int selectedPosition = v.getId();
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // item position is fetched here. this is exactly the same position of the selected item in your list
                int selectedPosition = v.getId();
            }
        });


    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation to your snippet.

Answer (score -1):

In my custom adapter I have:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

where position is the index of the row clicked. this should be accessible within your `onClick()` method.